"Add a comment" link does not redisplay popup window on the second click
Steps to reproduce:

Read a question on some site I do not belong to.
Click the "Add a comment" link.
The "Join this community" popup window appears.
Close the window by clicking the X in upper-right corner.
Click the link again.
I expected the popup window to be redisplayed, but nothing happens.

Macbook
Chrome Version 128.0.6613.138 (Official Build) (x86_64)

It appears that they intentionally have a short circuit which stops the "Add a comment" link from showing the signup modal twice. Removing the "working" status from the comment link restores the functionality $('.js-add-link.comments-link').working(false). It doesn't appear this status check applies to other options like the "follow" button.
